# Does changing a Postgresql table's tablespace compact it like "vacuum full" or "cluster"?

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces

I need to reclaim disk space in a table in a Postgresql 9.3.2 database to be used for other tables.  The standard suggestions to accomplish this are: "VACUUM FULL" or  "CLUSTER" or copy the contents into a flat file and copy them back in.  When moving an existing table to a new tablespace with an "ALTER TABLE" command, the table's contents are copied.  Can anyone tell me if they are compacted during the "ALTER TABLE" process?

Comment: Very good question; depends on whether the relfilenodes are copied or it's done as a relation rewrite. I'd have to check the source code. If you don't get a definitive answer soon, at-reply me and I'll go check.

Comment: I could very easily be wrong, but I was under the impression that postgres executed the alter tablespace on the table by simply moving the corresponding data file to the correct folder at the file-system level. If what I said above is true, then I doubt it would reclaim any space.

Answer (score 4):

The comments so far are roughly correct, but to give an authoritative answer from looking at src/backend/tablecmds.c:

If you're **only** performing `ALTER TABLE ... SET TABLESPACE ... ;`, then `ATExecSetTableSpace()` will be invoked to handle the `SET TABLESPACE`, and it uses `copy_relation_data()` to perform a WAL-logged block-by-block copy of the table. However, if you were to specify additional actions to the `ALTER TABLE` command which require table rewriting, then the new copy of the table should be built (and compacted) in the new tablespace via `ATRewriteTable()`.

Comment: Are there any trivial "additional actions" that will cause ATRewriteTable?  By "trivial" I mean "actions that won't break existing sql code".  Perhaps changing a column name to the same value as it is presently?

Comment: @sevzas it's going to depend on your exact PostgreSQL version and column type, but using something like `SET DATA TYPE some_int_col USING some_int_col::bigint::int` should probably work (just casting the column to its own type probably won't be enough to force a rewrite, depending on your PG version).

Answer (score 3):

The answer appears to be "moving the table to a different tablespace does *not* compact it like VACUUM FULL or CLUSTER".

I tested this by:

- creating a dummy table
- filling it with one million dummy rows to the tune of 38MB
- deleting all of the rows with "DELETE from DUMMY"
- moving table to a different tablespace with "ALTER TABLE DUMMY SET TABLESPACE overflow;"
- looking to see how big the table is on the new table space.

The query I used to determine the size of the table is this:

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    AND C.relkind <> 'i'
    AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC;
```